# ERROR zookeeper.ZooKeeperWatcher

Tags: hbase

I'm trying to learn HBase. I'm following [this tutorial](http://hbase.apache.org/0.94/book.html). I have passed until 1.2.3. But on 1.2.3, when I execute

```
hbase(main):003:0> create 'test', 'cf'
```

command, I get

```
ERROR zookeeper.ZooKeeperWatcher: hconnection0x0 Received unexpected KeeperException, re-throwing exception
org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for /hbase/hbaseid
```

What is the reason of this error and how can I fix it?

**EDIT**

If any additional information needed about the case, I can provide.

Answer (score -2):

You need to modify your hbase-site.xml file.

Comment: I have done it according to the tutorial. I do not think, this is the situation